# Rearranging An Equation To Solve?Can't?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

How would I rearrange the equation:

$$a=b^{(c/d)}$$

to find c?

Comment: Have you heard of logarithms?

Comment: take logarithm both sides and there you are!

Answer (score 3):

Notice

$$ a = b^{c/d} \iff \log a = \frac{c}{d} \log b \iff c =\frac{d \log a}{\log b}$$

provided $b \neq  1 $ otherwise we would have $\log b = 0 $ which is not allowed. and $b > 0 $. similarly, $a > 0$ and $ d \neq 0 $

Comment: Since the question is very easy with knowledge of logarithms, it might be helpful to specify the parameters that are necessary here.

Comment: I added . see updated solution